# Error being thrown by SSIS script task

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am working on upgrading 2005 SSIS packages to 2016.  I have upgraded this package but when I try to run it, it is breaking on the script task in the control flow.

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
#endregion

namespace ST_9752d9eb585d4a4d97a334ef01ccf313
{

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    public void Main()
    {

        string fileName;

        fileName = Dts.Variables["User::Source_File_And_Path"].Value.ToString();

        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(fileName))
        {
            w.Write("\r\n");
            w.Close();
        }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    #region ScriptResults declaration
    /// <summary>
    /// This enum provides a convenient shorthand within the scope of this class for setting the
    /// result of the script.
    /// 
    /// This code was generated automatically.
    /// </summary>
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

}
}
```

This script task is being used to add a CRLF onto the end of the data in the file.I have added breakpoints to the code and I'm seeing it is breaking at the line `using (StreamWriter w = file.AppendText(fileName))`. [I am receiving the following error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtO6j.jpg)

[image]

Here are the exception details:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>    HResult=-2147024809
>    Message=Illegal characters in path.
>    Source=mscorlib
>    StackTrace:
>
> > at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String fullPath)
> >     at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> >     at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> >     at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
> >     at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
> >     at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
> >     at System.IO.File.AppendText(String path)
> >     at ST_9752d9eb585d4a4d97a334ef01ccf313.ScriptMain.Main() in c:\Users\aluhman\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Vsta\5c1672d48682401d852b1b44649f951b\ScriptMain.cs:line 31
> >      InnerException:

This was all working in 2005 and this is a new error I'm seeing now in 2016.

Comment: Try copy exception detail to clipboard.  Then paste into Notepad.  Then error is probably due to the filename containing a character that is not allowed in a filename.

Comment: check your `fileName`

Comment: This is the file name "F:\\Data_Imports\\Company\\Inbound\\Customers_*.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open every file at once, instead you have to iterate over them one by one:

Something like:

```
string fileName = Dts.Variables["User::Source_File_And_Path"].Value.ToString();
string [] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetFullPath(fileName));
foreach (string f in fileEntries)
{
     if (Path.GetExtension(f).ToUpper()==".TXT".ToUpper() && f.StartsWith("Customers_")==true)
     {
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(f))
            {
                w.Write("\r\n");
                w.Close();
            }
     }
}
```